# Finding all subqueries in sql using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

Following regex `\(\s*select([^()]*)\)` giving all subqueries but it ignores when subquery contains any sql functions like max(), count(), ....etc
regex works for below

```
SELECT student.name, teacher.name, sub.subject_name
FROM student student
JOIN teacher teacher on teacher.id=student.teacher_id
JOIN (select subject.name subject_name, subject.id id from subject) sub on sub.id=teacher.subject_id 
where student.id=1
```

it finds subquery as `select subject.name subject_name, subject.id id from subject`
but not for

```
SELECT student.name, teacher.name, sub.subject_name
FROM student student
JOIN teacher teacher on teacher.id=student.teacher_id
JOIN (select group_concat(subject.name) subject_names from subject)
where student.id=1
```

it doesn't find match as `select group_concat(subject.name) subject_names from subject`
how can I get match...?

Comment: Please explain why you want the subqueries; there may be a different tactic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex `/\((?:[^()]|\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\))*\)/mg;`

[image: regex_subquery]

Comment: ``SELECT 'This is a string literal with (SELECT 1) substring';``

Comment: @Akina The `SELECT 'This is a string literal with (SELECT 1) substring';` example is not included in the OP question.

Comment: regex will failed, when there will be mathematical expression will which includes multiple open and closing brackets....

Answer (score 0):

Challenge accepted.  See if this leads to a viable solution:

```
mysql> explain select (select 'a' from t) x,
                      (select 'b' from t) y,
                      "select 'c'" z
                    from t;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4243 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | t     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4243 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | t     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4243 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Note
   Code: 1003
Message: /* select#1 */ select 
        (/* select#2 */ select 'a' from `covid`.`t`) AS `x`,
        (/* select#3 */ select 'b' from `covid`.`t`) AS `y`,
        'select \'c\'' AS `z`
     from `db`.`t`
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then parse the EXPLAIN by using the /*..*/ comments and balancing parens.

(I edited whitespace for effect.)